# Annotate functions that return Optional with @NonNull?

Tags: java, option-type

Why add `@NonNull` annotation when returning `Optional`?

```
public Optional<Integer> getInt() {
    return Optional.ofNullable(localInteger);
}
```

Vs

```
@NonNull
public Optional<Integer> getInt() {
    return Optional.ofNullable(localInteger);
}
```

Based on this article: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/java8-optional-2175753.html
My understanding of `Optional` with that article is that the whole point of `Optional` is to try and prevent checking for `null` in code and that when a function can return `null` it will instead return an `Optional` to force the caller to check if it `isPresent`.

I have since learned that there are issues with `Optional<Map>` described here: https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2015/08/optional-broken

So adding `@NonNull` for Optional seems to add extra clarity to the caller when returning a Map type but is this clarity required for all functions that return any `Optional` type?

```
public Optional<Integer> getInt() {
    return null;
}
```

Is as bad as

```
@NonNull
public Integer getInt() {
    return null;
}
```

Am I correct in thinking that it is bad practise to be returning `null` when the return type is `Optional`? (except for the above mentioned Map case or because there is a case where `null` is valid you should always add `@NonNull`?)

**Conclusion**
My conclusion so far is to not add `@NonNull` when returning `Optional` and if it can be `null` then annotate with `@Nullable` or better yet, don't return an `Optional` type.

Comment: Could you explain when it would _ever_ be correct to return a null rather than returning an "empty" Optional?

Comment: if you promise to return `Optional` but return `null` you break your contract. Just don't return `null`, return `Optional.empty()`. No additional annotations are needed.

Comment: @DaleWilson, see the developer.atlassian link in question for a detailed answer as to when.

Comment: @dehasi, I agree completely. However I have someone convinced otherwise and looking to the community to see if I am missing something.

Comment: @RiaanSchutte  Thanks for pointing out the article.  I read it but I don't buy it.  The author thinks there is a (very obscure) defect [*] in the design of Optional, and proposes returning null as a work-around.  In this case the "cure" is far worse than the "sickness" and I agree with dehasi.  You should never return null when you have promised an Optional. [note *]  My tldr; version of the "defect" is Optional cannot contain `null` in the case where there IS a return value and that value happens to be `null`.

Comment: Adding @NonNull wouldn't hurt much, but it's a pleonasm, it doesn't add any value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your comments. It would seem my understanding lines up with the comments.

Returning `null` when `Optional` is "promised" seems to be generally accepted as **bad**.

I completely agree based on the purpose of what Optional was designed for.

**However**... We have had to make a special note in our company docs for this due to the lack of documentation in `Optional` making it explicitly clear that you should not return `null` when returning an `Optional`.

Answer (score 0):

`@NotNull` asserts at runtime when a `null` value was found. Therefore it absolutely makes sense to add this annotation for all methods that return `Optional`s, since a caller of that method expects it to never return `null` and rather use `Optional.empty()`.

The use of `@NotNull` would help to prevent these `null` values traversing through the application and causing strange NPEs in different parts. That helps to debug issues and find the source of the problem quicker.

IMHO methods that return `Optional`s should be marked as `@NotNull` by the compiler automatically, it would be nice if there was a setting/plugin to do that.

**Update:** as I learned [in a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51878106/make-java-infer-notnull-for-optional-return-types), there exists the [CheckerFramework](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#nullness-checker) which goes one step further and allows to check for null problems at **compile time**. It might be harder to integrate in a huge project than the runtime annotations, but it makes the code bas much safer. There is a [very good tutorial](https://github.com/glts/safer-spring-petclinic/wiki) for migrating a small example project as well.

Comment: Hi @fabb, Note that the `@NonNull` attribute generates no code for function return values. It only generates runtime checking for parameters of a funciton. If it did generate code I would absolutely agree with you! But this is in the end a documentation issue. To add `@NonNull` as a documentation aid or to not add it as you should not be returning null when Optionals are being returned. See the very last paragraph on lomboks website detailing this in the [small print](https://projectlombok.org/features/NonNull) at the bottom of the page.

Comment: @RiaanSchutte I use a different `@NotNull` implementation from `org.jetbrains.annotation` which indeed does work on return values.

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/nullable-and-notnull-annotations.html

Comment: that is correct for developers using IntelliJ only. But the general note of enforcing `@NotNull` on such functions that return `Optional` still only add a documentation attribute for all other non IntelliJ developers and for CI Build pipelines. If it adds an advantage to you, then add it but enforcing it at a company wide level is not appropriate given the goal of what `Optional` is for.