# Make Java infer @NotNull for Optional Return Types

Tags: java, option-type, notnull

Using `Optional`s in Java does not protect from NPEs since values still can be `null`:

```
Optional<String> myMethod() {
    return null;
}
```

A way to protect from this at least at runtime is the use of `@NotNull` annotations. (Not possible at compile time in Java since it does not have non-null references, as opposed to more sophisticated languages like Swift and Kotlin).

Using `@NotNull` will immediately crash when `null` is detected, thus preventing `null` traversing through the program, and making it easier to pinpoint error sources. It's best combined with Unit Tests to make it resilient against breaking due to refactorings.

As far as I can tell, it always makes sense to use `@NotNull` for `Optional` return values and parameters.

Now here's the question:
Is it somehow possible to make Java infer `@NotNull` automatically for `Optional` return values and parameters? I.e. I don't have to write it for every use, but rather have that behaviour by setting some build setting or similar?

Comment: You can use return Optional.empty();

Comment: This sounds more like an IDE feature.

Comment: @SudhirOjha no, I want to catch the error early if `null` is returned/received as early as possible.

Comment: @PinkieSwirl more like a missing language feature... Maybe it could be resolved by some annotation processing tool? Or maybe there really is some IDE plugin or linter (CheckStyle?) to help with this?

Comment: @fabb ofcourse it would be nice if it would be a language feature, but you already mentioned some that support that. AFAIK intellij idea supports that, but maybe not in the way you want (it adds a gutter icon)

Comment: one thing that I have in mind, but boy this would be insane, it to instrument the byte code and do `referenceOfOptional.getClass` (discarding the result), and if it's null, it will fail. Otherwise how far can you think that code will go, until someone gets a possibly return type of `Optional`? I don't know, so you would want to do that for `Integer` and all other boxed primitives, since *they* might be null? sounds like too much to me...

Comment: Phew, now that‘s a crazy idea 

Comment: You could add CheckerFramework to build process: https://checkerframework.org/manual/#nullness-checker

Comment: CheckerFramework looks interesting, thanks! I fear that it will take a lot of time for our huge framework, but that‘s another story.

Comment: @user158037 would you like to add your comment as an answer? I‘d accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Optional is not designed to keep only non null values  . It may contain null values as well. So your proposal is against the design of the Optional.

Comment: I am aware that a reference of type Optional might either be empty or null. I want to find a way, using helper tools if necessary, to guarantee the null case never happens, or at least immediately throws at runtime (as in the case of @NotNull).